# i don't know what is wrong with this syntax

Tags: mysql, flask

```
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
cur.execute("""Select Qid, Username, Question, StdName, SubName, PostDate, AnsCount from user
            inner join Textual_Question, subjects, standard where
            Textual_Question.Qid = {} and
            user.Uid = Textual_Question.Uid and
            Textual_Question.Subject = subjects.Subkey and
            ​Textual_Question.standard =standard.StdKey""".format(Qid))
```

(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '} and\n        user.Uid = Textual_Question.Uid and\n        Textual_Question.Subje' at line 3")

Comment: Don't use comma style joins, and definitely don't mix them with regular joins (although this doesn't relate to your specific issue). For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I guess you missed the closing parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed the closing parentheses.

```
cur.execute("""Select Qid, Username, Question, StdName, SubName, PostDate, AnsCount from user
                inner join Textual_Question, subjects, standard where
                Textual_Question.Qid = '{0}' and
                user.Uid = Textual_Question.Uid and
                Textual_Question.Subject = subjects.Subkey and
                ​Textual_Question.standard = standard.StdKey""".format(Qid))
```